# What paper should a design print shop have on hand?

Tags: paper

I am building a co-working space for the design industry. I want it to have excellent printing facilities. Right now I'm working on sourcing papers. What paper types and weights would be a good starting point and why?

Comment: Paper choice depends on what kind of print job you are doing, and what your client wants, and where you live with respect to brand availability - all of which you have failed to mention.

Comment: Also, your choice of substrates will depend on (and possibly be dictated by) your printing machinery. Photocopiers, wide format ink-jet printers, letterpress machines, vinyl cutters, etc all have very different requirements and restrictions. E.G. I would expect "excellent printing facilities" to include colour calibrated output which would require specific paper to function properly.

Comment: The location is Melbourne....the motive for the question is to broaden my offering ...more than my printernrecommendation.  All responses GREATLY appreciated. Tks Westside and Billy

Comment: I think the only *sure* thing is offset white in various weights :)

Comment: Hey @Snp we're discussing your question here: https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/why-is-this-question-about-paper-selections-too-broad --- I think if you [edit] to include what types of printers and work you're looking at doing we can get this reopened and a really good question.